# OneNote Class Notebook API: Embed Sway, Mix, Youtube and other iframe content via API

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

We are able to add Youtube, Sway and Office Mix content using the "Online Videos" ribbon command in OneNote 2016 with Class Notebook Add-in which are played in place when a user accesses them.

We want to be able to do the same and embed iframes of external content via OneNote Class Notebook or Notebook API but couldn't find any documentation for the same.

Please help with the HTML/XML tags/markup to use to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the POST or PATCH ~/pages API by adding the following iframe component in the html request body.

NOTE: This is an example only:

```html
<iframe width="600" height="338" data-original-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-BOSpxYJ9M"></iframe>
```

The important part is to specify the data-original-src attribute. And note this is the original url of the video (not the embed url e.g. the url fetched in sites like youtube from clicking Share).